# Initialize a jQuery function in React's JSX

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jsx

Good morning, guys. 
I've been trying all weekend to initialize this jQuery "Sticky-Kit" function inside my JSX and haven't been able to:

```
$(".product-intro__images").stick_in_parent({
    offset_top: 10
})
```

I placed it as it goes inside the JSX, then i placed it in another Javascript file. I actually checked the console and I do have the GET calling working but nothing happens. Then I realize, as ReactJS works with a Virtual DOM that this must be a problem with the synchronization.

As you can see, I'm tring to call a class named "product-intro__images" which is a column inside a parent div named "product-intro". Here you can see it:

```
<div className="product-intro__images">
      <div className="product-gallery">
          <ul className="product-gallery-thumbs__list">
            {images.map(function(imageProps) {
              return (
                <li className="product-gallery-thumbs__item" key={ imageProps.src }>
                  <img src={ imageProps.src } alt={ imageProps.alt } />
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
          <div className="flexslider">
              <ul className="slides product-gallery-images__list">
                  <li className="product-gallery-images__item"><img src={("http://placehold.it/1000x1000/76BD22")} /></li>
                  <li className="product-gallery-images__item"><img src={("http://placehold.it/1000x1000/FFC82E")} /></li>
                  <li className="product-gallery-images__item"><img src={("http://placehold.it/1000x1000/0084D9")} /></li>
                  <li className="product-gallery-images__item"><img src={("http://placehold.it/1000x1000/76BD22")} /></li>
                  <li className="product-gallery-images__item"><img src={("http://placehold.it/1000x1000/FFC82E")} /></li>
                  <li className="product-gallery-images__item"><img src={("http://placehold.it/1000x1000/0084D9")} /></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Just beside this column there's another one named "product-intro__details" which is supposed to be scrolled as this one, "product-intro__images" remains sticked to its parent div. Each one of this columns has been placed inside a const, and by extension, inside a component which is rendering as it follows:

```
return 
(
  <body id="product-page" className={modalClass} >
    <section className="page-section ps-product-intro">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="product-intro">
          {ProductImages}
          {ProductDetails}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
```

So basically here's the thing: How am I supposed to call this jQuery function?

PS: there's another javascript, of course, named sticky-kit.min.js which has been called already by a require method inside my application.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your component's render:

```
<div className="product-intro__images" ref={el => this.productIntro = el}>
```

then:

```
componentDidMount(){
  $(this.productIntro).stick_in_parent()
}
```

you could even do this in the ref callback direct:

```
ref={el => $(el).stick_in__parent()}
```

But keep in mind it's not a great idea to mix in stuff that manages DOM for you with React code direct and it depends on the plugin - but unexpected behaviour or side effects may occur.

You may also need to cleanup on `componentWillUnmount(){}`

Make sure you `import $ from 'jquery'` and the plugin as well.

Comment: Well, I tried your answer and it worked! Thank you very, very much!